# Obscure words for commonplace concepts

Tags: single-word-requests

There are concepts familiar to everyone (e.g “the smell of earth after rain”, “the warmth of the sun in winter”) which have obscure (i.e not familiar to everyone) names (petrichor and apricity, respectively).

Is there a word in English for these names? I’m looking for a single word to replace the phrase “obscure names for familiar concepts”?

Comment: So you're looking for an obscure word for  "scientific coinage".  You'll have to coin it.

Comment: If there is a word for this, I think it describes itself. :)